# Use AWS CodeCommit from different organisations

Tags: aws-codecommit

My case is follow:
There are 3 AWS organisations 111 , 222, 333 and I have IAM User from organisation 111. To use some resources from organisations 222 and 333 I'm using assume role. Now I have CodeCommit repository in organisation 222. Is it possible somehow to access those repository from organisation 333 CodeBuild and to use it as Source there? I cannot create/use users in 222 , 333 organisation? The only what I can do it to create roles.